# how to pass a data from one android application to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast

I'm developing one app, I need to execute some functionality in one app from the result of another app,  **how to I pass a data from one to another** ,Please give me any example programs for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Go to this link [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Comment: You can use shared preferences or broadcast depending on your data.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu please tell me How?

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `Json` or `XMl`. Read the `Json` from the url that the another app that wants to read and

post data in form of the json or xml to the url

For Api level 14 or getter [ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use content provider for this but i dont use this personally. what i do. I make a folder in sd card and the data that i want to share, is place in that folder and then access that data from other application becuse i know all the things that i used in creating that folder or whatever thing like database etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best Option is to Use to shared Preferences ,which will help passing data between apllications and the main note if you uninstall parent application shared preferences will get deleted,,,,

```
private SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;
    mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PrefName",
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
    mPrefsEditor.putString("tagName", "value");
    mPrefsEditor.commit();
```

and in your next application or activity

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
Context myContext = createPackageContext("com.example", 
Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); // where com.example is the owning  app containing the preferences
  SharedPreferences testPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences 
("PrefName", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 


Map<String, ?> items = testPrefs .getAll();
for(String s : items.keySet()){
    //do somthing like String value=  items.get(s).toString());
    }
```

Comment: But if I'm not mistaken, using BroadcastReceiver is a better way to do this.

Comment: @Banscan Kayaoglu, how to use BroadcastReceiver here?

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE is now deprecated, don't use it

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE has been deprectaed now and should be avoided as much as possible. It is not safe to expose your data to the world.